# PHP Function - Error Passing Form Field as Parameter

Tags: php, spam-prevention

I created the following function to strip web addresses from submitted form fields. I did this as a spam prevention measure.

```
<?PHP
function scrubURL($field)
{
    return preg_replace('@((https?://)?([-\\w]+\\.[-\\w\\.]+)+\\w(:\\d+)?(/([-\\w/_\\.]*    (\\?\\S+)?)?)*)(?:[?&]\S+=\S*)*@i', '', $_POST[$field]);
}
?>
```

I try to reference the function in my form processing:
$_POST['first'] = scrubURL($_POST['first']);

I'm getting the error: Undefined index: http:// somewebsite.com

Somehow, it's passing the value from the form rather then the field itself. I tried wrapping the field in quotes, scrubURL("$_POST['first']") and got the error: syntax error, unexpected 'first' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'

I can not see the cause as I did thin successfully on another form. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: function definition says it takes the field name, but you try to pass the field value to it. this is wrong: ```$_POST['first'] = scrubURL($_POST['first']);``` and this is right: ```$_POST['first'] = scrubURL('first');```

Comment: oops. I removed $_POST from the function as the field could be $_GET and it works. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function argument `$field` contains the value of `$_POST['first']`! What you want in your sample is a function call like

```
$_POST['first'] = scrubURL('first');
```

Just as a recommendation: I would not to access `$_POST` in your function. It's cleaner code. ;)

```
function scrubURL($dirtyUrl)
{
    return preg_replace('@((https?://)?([-\\w]+\\.[-\\w\\.]+)+\\w(:\\d+)?(/([-\\w/_\\.]*    (\\?\\S+)?)?)*)(?:[?&]\S+=\S*)*@i', '', $dirtyUrl);
}

$_POST['first'] = scrubURL($_POST['first']);
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code it seems you just need to pass "first" as the param:

```php
$result = scrubURL('first');
```